# jquery getting name of span in links

Tags: jquery

In my page I have links as follows.

```
<a><span id="word-0">dog</span></a>
<a><span id="word-1">cat</span></a>
```

I want to get the text of the span, when clicked the links in jquery, how can I do that?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsg7t/)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('a').click(function () {
 alert( $(this).find('span').text());
});
```